# List of objects seems to generate No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: java, spring

I have this basic method which should return a list of users, somehow I can't get the objects value and it causes CORS error in the frontend

```
public List<Users> getAll(){
    
    List<Users> list= usersRepo.findAll();      
    System.out.println(list);
    
    return list;
}
```

The User object contains multiple field such as "name" "surname" "email" "address" etc.

This is the System.out output:

```
[it.demo.demoProject.db.entity.User@521ab19, it.demo.demoProject.db.entity.User@f9se81f it.demo.demoProject.db.entity.User@sd65f19]
```

I'm working with both FE and BE running on the same pc and I allowed all origins just to test if it works

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@GetMapping(path = "/getAll", produces = "application/jason")
public ResponseEntity<?> getAll(){
    
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).headers(new HttpHeaders()).body(anagDipService.getAll());
    
}
```

What else should I try?

Comment: Your problem is probably your server-side [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) configuration and not the type of content... Did you check your CORS config? Please post your code here.

Answer (score 0):

add a cross filter in your java code for more detail read below blog

https://howtodoinjava.com/java/servlets/java-cors-filter-example/